# Microphone not working ASUS Zenith II Extreme Alpha

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I can't get any input from my microphone (part of headset) on my ASUS Zenith II Extreme Alpha desktop running Ubuntu 20.04.  I've tried many things I found while researching online, but none have helped.  The microphone works fine under Windows 10 (dual boot).  Sound settings give two options for sound: 1) Analog Input -USB Audio, and 2) Digital Input (S/PDIF) - USB Audio.  Neither of these work for the microphone.  The headphones do work.  If I run the command:

```
cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
```

I get only:

```
Codec: Nvidia GPU 91 HDMI/DP
```

The MOBO uses a SupremeFX S1220A High Definition Audio CODEC, which is a custom version of the Realtek ALC1220.  Lastly, if I plug the headset 3.5mm jack into a USB-C adapter, and select "Headset Microphone - Headphone adapter" it works.  Unfortunately, I don't want to use the adapter due to other reasons.  Any suggestions?

Comment: After more investigation / trials, I was able to make recordings with "arecord".  "arecord -l" gives 1 card with 3 devices.  Using the command 'arecord -f S16_LE -c 2 -r 48000 -d 10 --device="hw:1,2" test.wav' I was able to record the microphone.  Note that both inputs listed in sound settings still do not register anything.

Comment: After more investigation / trials, I used alsamixer to increase the microphone volume.  Yes, the microphone shows up on alsamixer and arecord can capture and record input from the microphone.  However, gnome settings / sound doesn't detect any sound when I speak into the microphone on either the Analog Input or the Digital Input selections.